# Aligning text in the multicols environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, multicol

Here's the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\noindent Author A \newline
Department Name, \newline
University Name, \newline
City, Country. \newline
Email: ABC@gmail.com

\columnbreak

\noindent Author B \newline
Department Name, \newline
University Name, \newline
City, Country. \newline
Email: XYZ@gmail.com
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

How can I make the right column right indented, just like the left column is left indented, to make sure the text in the right column is aligned with the little black line which is supposed to be the end of the page on the right hand side.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use multicols? I would do this with two tabulars and \hfill between them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not really. How would the tabular environment work if I don't want it to print a vertical line between  the columns?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried that and it actually produces worse ouput. Is there any way I can simply shift the right column more toward the right, without having to right justify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I did understand the alignment you want to get. In case that the second author shouldn't be set flushright change the tabular column type from `r` to `l`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
Author A \\
Department Name, \\
University Name, \\
City, Country. \\
Email: ABC@gmail.com
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
Author B \\
Department Name, \\
University Name, \\
City, Country. \\
Email: XYZ@gmail.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}` for the second author:

[image]